# Pass list with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
$("#allphotos").click(function () {

                $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
                        modal: true,
                        height: 1000,
                        width: 1000
                    })
                    .load("/Home/AllPhotos", data);

            });
```

And this method:

```
public ActionResult AllPhotos()
        {
            var listofPhotos =
                RavenSession.Query<ContentPage>()
                    .Where(o => o.Template.ContentPageType == "aPhoto_web.Models.Photography, aPhoto_web")
                    .AsProjection<Photography>()                  
                    .ToList();
            var avm = new AdminViewModel();
            avm.Photographys = listofPhotos;

            return PartialView("_allPhoto", avm.Photographys);


        }
```

The method returns a list of photographys that i would like the Jquery to display in a dialog. Im pretty sure this line:

```
.load("/Home/AllPhotos", data);
```

Is the problem. Any ideas of what to try?

VIEW:

```
@model aPhoto_web.Models.AdminPages.AdminViewModel
           <h1>Test to see if dialog is empty...and it is</h1>
 @foreach (var item in Model.Photographys)
 {
     <img src="@item.ImgUrl"/>
 }
```

Comment: What result do you get now? What doesn't work?

Comment: Does this method is called?

Comment: The result is an empty dialog.
Yes, the method gets called.

Comment: You are not expecting any parameter in your controller, try just `.load("/Home/AllPhotos");`

Comment: No parameters. Im starting to think that there is a problem wit the view im trying to pass. Even if i harcode in some <p>Hello</p> in it it is empty..

Comment: Can you see the dialog now ?

Comment: I can see the dialog but it is empty

Comment: Can you please show your view `_allPhoto` ?

Comment: I added the view to the update!

Comment: instead of returning avm.Photographys return avm only in partialviewresult

Comment: Try `return PartialView("_allPhoto", avm);`, your view is expecting `AdminViewModel`.

Comment: You both solved for me at the same time it seems! Thanks a lot!
I see Exception was a little bit faster in the comments. But I thank you both equally =)

Comment: @user2915962...i deserve a upvote also...hahaha...Thankzz...glad to know that my help worked for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Url.Action and remove **data** from .load() because you don't want to send anything to controller as :

```
$("#allphotos").click(function () {

            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
                    modal: true,
                    height: 1000,
                    width: 1000
                })
                .load(@Url.Action("AllPhotos", "Home");
        });
```

**and correct return type of AllPhotos because your partial view is expecting AdminViewModel object.**

```
public ActionResult AllPhotos()
        {
            var listofPhotos =
                RavenSession.Query<ContentPage>()
                    .Where(o => o.Template.ContentPageType == "aPhoto_web.Models.Photography, aPhoto_web")
                    .AsProjection<Photography>()                  
                    .ToList();
            var avm = new AdminViewModel();
            avm.Photographys = listofPhotos;

            return PartialView("_allPhoto", avm); <---------


        }
```

Comment: what is "data" that you are passing in .load()..??@user2915962

Comment: yup =) thats the problem, i do not know how to take care of the result from the method(a view) and pass it to the dialog

Comment: @user2915962...there must be a problem in AllPhotos action just check ....in visual studio if you have error in partialview it donot show you have to carefully check for problems...

Answer (score 1):

You are not expecting any parameter in your controller, try this in your JavaScript code.

```
.load("/Home/AllPhotos");
```

And try this in your view.

```
return PartialView("_allPhoto", avm);
```

Your view is expecting `AdminViewModel`.